# jQuery and asp.net not playing nice together

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Please refer to this page for reference: http://loadedgranola.valitics.com/_product_83484/blackberry_lime

I have a jQuery script that runs to replace the h1 tags with a background image. It works great when the document loads but when I click "add to cart", after the javascript alert the jQuery styling breaks. Due to CMS restrictions I have no direct access to their javascript or any of the ASP files but I assume there has to be an easy fix to this.

The code I'm using:

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

```
            var textReplacer = document.title.replace(/ /g,'');
            jQuery("h1").addClass('replaced').css("background","url(../images/h1/" + textReplacer + ".png) no-repeat 0 0");
    });
```

I have also tried using the function pageLoad(sender, args) { magic but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go ..

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
       jQuery('<style type="text/css" media="screen">h1{text-indent:-9999px!important;background:url(../images/h1/'+document.title.replace(/ /g,'') +'.png) no-repeat 0 0!important;}</style>').appendTo('head');
});
```

what it does is add a new css rule that pushes the text way out of the box and adds the background image

Comment: Wow, not the solution I was thinking of but this works great!

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what is happening:**

When you submit the shopping cart it's doing an AJAX call. The result of that call replaces most of the HTML on the page. Any changes you made before that get replaced.

**Possible Solution**

You would have to run that replace script again after the AJAX call is complete.

**Questions**

Why are you replacing the H1 tags on load? What problem are you trying to solve? You might be able to find a better CSS solution.

Comment: Thanks! The designer wants all the headers in Clarendon. I first attempted this with sIFR (so it isn't exclusively a jQuery problem) but encountered the same problem I am having now. Instead, I have made images of all the headers and am using css to give the text a negative margin off of the page and inserting the picture in the background. I was hoping to create a function that would pull the document.title like "blackberry lime" in this example, strip the spaces out, and add a .png to the end of it. That way I could write 2 lines of code as opposed to a separate CSS class for each header...

Comment: Personally I wouldn't add more JavaScript complexity that could be replaced with a few more lines of CSS. Whatever works best for you though.

Comment: true .. but he needs dynamic css rule (the image in the background should change according to page)